# Special class on Jumbotron hiding H1 title

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I’ve added a ‘special’ class to a Jumbotron to keep the Jumbotron's height 100% of the users browser window (no matter what size).

However when I apply this class to a `div` within the jumbotron (greenpromobox) is sitting on top of my headline and thus hiding the `H1` headline (which is in the Jumbotron) on mobile devices.

Any ideas on a solution?

**Live link:** http://185.123.96.102/~kidsdrum/moneynest.co.uk

**HTML**

```
<div class="special">
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <div class="container text-center">
            <div class="h1extrapadding hidden-xs hidden-sm"></div>  
            <h1 class="boldme">Aged 20-30 & frustrated with money?</h1> 

            <div class="greenpromobox">
                <div class="h2extrapadding hidden-xs hidden-sm"></div>  
                <h2 class="boldme">Take our free <b class="jumpstarttext">Jumpstart Your Finances</b> class to<br /> quickly gain control over your finances</h2>

                <!-- Begin MailChimp Signup Form -->
                <div id="mc_embed_signup">
                    <form action="//moneynest.us11.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=9ccf2d2219536b32eaae3c3d1&amp;id=299de51b4e" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>
                        <div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll">

                        <img src="http://185.123.96.102/~kidsdrum/moneynest.co.uk/img/hand-drawn-arrow.png" id="handarrow" class="hidden-xs hidden-sm" alt="arrow"><input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="email" id="mce-EMAIL" placeholder="Enter your email address" required autofocus>
                        <!-- real people should not fill this in and expect good things - do not remove this or risk form bot signups-->
                        <div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;" aria-hidden="true">
                            <input type="text" name="b_9ccf2d2219536b32eaae3c3d1_299de51b4e" tabindex="-1" value="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="clear">
                            <input type="submit" value="Start Class Now" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="text-uppercase btn btn-primary btn-lg"></div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
               <!--End mc_embed_signup-->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.special,.special .jumbotron{
    height:100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I'm not seeing this.. Have you fixed it?

I have noticed that the bottom of the green box gets cropped on mobiles.

Comment: No I haven't fixed it did you try it on a mobile or just by resizing? Seemed to be different when I actually viewed it on my iPhone.

Comment: iPhone 4S was the phone I used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removed:

```
.special,.special .jumbotron{
    height:100%;
}
```

Added

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
.special,.special .jumbotron
{height: 100%;
}
}
```

This stopped the Jumbotron forcing 100% height on mobiles which was causing the elements to be hidden.

Sam

Answer (score 0):

Yes.. On a 5s. Is your phone up to date?

[image]

Comment: Brilliant thanks, yes my phone is up-to-date.

Hmm odd the bottom of the greenpromodiv seems to be missing, any idea why this is?

Comment: Your jumbotron is set to overflow: hidden. The content at that size is taller than the jumbotron so is being cropped. If you make the content smaller on that size screen this it will be fine. Don't forget that in landscape it will be shorter still.

Comment: Good point, seems to stem from the height of the input email box, if I change the px to % it doesn't seem to work?

Comment: Set the size based on the screen size using a media query. You should also make the h1 and h2 a much smaller font size on a phone.

Comment: Thanks, I assumed Bootstrap would do this for me? Considering it's mobile first?

Comment: Mobile first just means that it defaults to the mobile sizes. If you want different settings for different screen sizes you need to set them. For mobile first, in your css you might set the font size to 12px in your main but then use media queries for the larger sizes. That way older mobile devices that do not have retina displays still display it correctly.

Comment: Interesting, since I haven't set any media queries for my h1 how come my H1 heading scales to different sizes when viewed on mobile ect?

Comment: It doesn't normally but it appears that the jumbotron has a larger font size set for screens over 768 pixels wide - .jumbotron .h1,.jumbotron h1{font-size:63px}. You will want to override this in your own css. Also on my phone your page now appears to have the top cropped off behind the header menu.